# How to set and get a parent class attribute from an inherited class in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have the `Family` and its inherited `Person` classes. How do I get the `familyName` attribute from the `Person` class?

```
class Family(object):
    def __init__(self, familyName):
        self.familyName = familyName

class Person(Family):
    def __init__(self, personName):
        self.personName = personName
```

For instance, let these `Family` and `Person` objects:

```
strauss = Family('Strauss')
johaness = Person('Johaness')
richard = Person('Richard')
```

I'd like to do something such as:

```
print richard.familyName
```

and get `'Strauss'`. How can I do this?

Comment: This is not proper use of inheritance. Inheritance represents the IS-A relationship, but a person is not a kind of family.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You cannot.

Instances only inherit the parent class methods and attributes, not *instance* attributes. You should not confuse the two.

`strauss.familyName` is an *instance* attribute of a `Family` instance. The `Person` instances would have their *own* copies of the `familyName` attribute.

You normally would code the `Person` constructor to take two arguments:

```
class Person(Family):
    def __init__(self, personName, familyName):
        super(Person, self).__init__(familyName)
        self.personName = personName

johaness = Person('Johaness', 'Strauss')
richard = Person('Richard', 'Strauss')
```

An alternative approach would be for `Person` to hold a reference to a `Family` instance:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, personName, family):
        self.personName = personName
        self.family = family
```

where `Person` no longer inherits from `Family`. Use it like:

```
strauss = Family('Strauss')
johaness = Person('Johaness', strauss)
richard = Person('Richard', strauss)

print johaness.family.familyName
```

Comment: Good presentation of options!

Comment: Ik this was 7 years ago, but I found a way to get instance attributes, class_name.__init__(self)

Comment: @AdityaKendre: that would not work, because here `Family.__init__()` takes an argument, `familyName`. That's why the proper fix is adding the `familyName` argument to the `Person.__init__()` method, and then calling `super().__init__(familyName)`. Your `class_name.__init__(self)` version would also work, if you passed in the extra arguments, so `Family.__init__(self, familyName)`. That's just an alternate way of calling the parent class, whereas `super().__init__()` will keep working when using multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Martijns suggestions, you can also create the Person from the Family instance, that way letting the family keep track of it's members:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, person_name, family):
        self.person_name = person_name
        self.family = family

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join((self.person_name, self.family.family_name))

class Family(object):
    def __init__(self, family_name):
        self.family_name = family_name
        self.members = []

    def add_person(self, person_name):
        person = Person(person_name, self)
        self.members.append(person)
        return person

    def __str__(self):
        return 'The %s family: ' % self.family_name + ', '.join(str(x) for x in self.members)
```

Usage like this:

```
>>> strauss = Family('Strauss')
>>> johannes = strauss.add_person('Johannes')
>>> richard = strauss.add_person('Richard')
>>> 
>>> print johannes
Johannes Strauss
>>> print richard
Richard Strauss
>>> print strauss
The Strauss family: Johannes Strauss, Richard Strauss
```