# How to change variable of main class from inherited class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to change object variable directly from inherited class.
Here is my code example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,initVal=0):
        self.myVal = initVal

    def worker(self):
        self.incrementor = B()
        self.incrementor.incMyVal(5)        

class B(A):
    def incMyVal(self,incVal):
        super().myVal += incVal

obj = A(5)
print(obj.myVal)

obj.worker()
print(obj.myVal)
```

But it doesn't work:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'myVal'
```

I also tried to use global/nonlocal keywords with my variable in B class, but no luck.

In my main case, the `B` class is an event handler. And it should change the attribute of an object when an event fires. So I'm not able to use `return` in the `incMyVal` method.

Comment: `myVal` is not a class attribute. It is an attribute on *instances* and instances have no 'parent' classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989217/how-to-set-and-get-a-parent-class-attribute-from-an-inherited-class-in-python

Comment: @Gnqz: I fail to see the relationship here.

Comment: You're trying to do something very silly is what you're doing wrong. If you're passing a value to another object so that it can change your value *you could have just changed your own value*.

Comment: @WayneWerner: this was just a sample code. MartijnPieters answered, exactly what i wanted

Comment: Obviously it's sample code, but the sample problem is way different from a real problem you would face. That's part of a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super()` can only search for *class attributes* in the class MRO, not instance attributes. `myVal` is set on an *instance* of the class, not on a class itself.

There is only ever one instance; it doesn't matter if code from class `A` or a derived class is altering attributes on an instance, it is just one namespace.

However, in your case, you shouldn't even be using inheritance. You are trying to use an *independent, second instance* to alter the attributes of an instance of `A`. Class inheritance doesn't give you access to *instances* of the base class like this.

Refactor `B` to take an instance of `A`, then act on that instance:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, ainstance):
        self.ainstance = ainstance
    def incMyVal(self, incVal):
        self.ainstance.myVal += incVal
```

Note that `B` is not a subclass of `A` here; it is not a (specialised) object of the same type at all; it is a different kind of thing, something that increments attributes of another object.

Pass in the instance when you create an instance of `B`:

```
def worker(self):
    self.incrementor = B(self)
    self.incrementor.incMyVal(5)
```

This does create a circular reference, which can keep objects alive for longer than perhaps needed. You may want to use a [weak reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) instead:

```
import weakref

class B:
    def __init__(self, ainstance):
        self.ainstance_ref = weakref.ref(ainstance)
    def incMyVal(self, incVal):
        ainstance = self.ainstance_ref()
        if ainstance is not None:
            ainstance.myVal += incVal
```

Now `B` instances only hold a weak reference to their `A` instance, and will do nothing if that instance no longer exists.